# In mapreduce why don't mappers send output keyvalues directly to reducers via network?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

I know that mappers write their output to node local disk before shuffle data to reducers. But why can't they send data directly to their corresponding reducers (shuffle on the fly) and let reducers do the sort and rest.

I've been thinking about what's good with local stores. First data is persisted on disk but even if one mapper fails the already persisted intermediate key-values will be cleared and another mapper will start from the beginning. Second there's bandwidth consideration but the data will be sent to reducers anyway in the end. We can send block by block to reduce the network overhead.

Perhaps the key reason lies in the merge sort process. If data is not sorted before being sent to reducers they may become bottlenecks.

Comment: You are pointing to creating a optimization and that was SPARK my friend :D

Answer (score 2):

> why can't they send data directly to their corresponding reducers (shuffle on the fly) and let reducers do the sort and rest.

Once the key-value pairs arrive at reducers, shuffling and sorting are meaningless. Shuffling and sorting happens before reducers receive inputs. It starts even before any reducer is launched to save the waiting time. Saved key-value pairs is a result of early start of this phase. After mappers complete, they are dispatched immediately to launch a reducer when the grouping filled up the quota for a reducer task. And sorting is global in order to avoid same key arriving at different reducers.

> I've been thinking about what's good with local stores.

Not sure what you mean by local stores. But `HDFS` by default replicates your data on multiple nodes to (1) tolerate risk of disk failures, and (2) allow more flexible assignment of the first layer of mappers (reading is always a layer of mapper).

> First data is persisted on disk but even if one mapper fails the already persisted intermediate key-values will be cleared and another mapper will start from the beginning.

As a mapper process, they do not keep pointer to their own output. Let's say after processing 10 lines of input, the mapper has written 97 lines out key-value pairs. Then the mapper crashes during processing of the 11-th line of input, after writing 3 extra key-value pairs. The mapper do not know it has written 97 lines before the start of 11-th line parsing. It cannot backtrack.

Note: Maybe some setting will enable this backtracking. I am not sure.

> Second there's bandwidth consideration but the data will be sent to reducers anyway in the end. We can send block by block to reduce the network overhead.

Again, you cannot send any data before all mapper finishes, because you cannot make sure the incoming key-value pairs doesn't belong to the block you want to send early.

Comment: Thanks that's very elaborative and useful. There's no point to launch reducers before all mappers finish so there are no reducers to send data to.